# Timestamp is not recognized Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a string value in snowflake as follows;

```
"2018-03-08T22:43:23.848Z"

"2018-03-19T18:56:02.886Z"

"2018-03-06T12:39:57.432Z"
```

Am trying to convert I into timestamp format using following code;

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(col_name::VARCHAR)
```

I used VARCHAR to get rid of double quotes. But am getting following error;

```
Timestamp '{"dayOfMonth":28,"dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY","dayOfYear":87,"hour":3,"minute":13,"month":"MARCH","monthValue":3,"nano":493000000,"offset":{"id":"Z","rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"totalSeconds":0},"second":17,"year":2018}' is not recognized
```

Kindly advise if my syntax is wrong or there are better ways to handle this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Timestamp '{"dayOfMonth":28,"dayOfWeek":"WEDNESDAY","dayOfYear":87,"hour":3,"minute":13,"month":"MARCH","monthValue":3,"nano":493000000,"offset":{"id":"Z","rules":{"fixedOffset":true,"transitionRules":[],"transitions":[]},"totalSeconds":0},"second":17,"year":2018}' is not recognized

This error implies that the JSON string in the error message is contaminated to the column, and then `TO_TIMESTAMP()` fails to parse the value because it's not a timestamp-like string.

At first, you should check your application to determine why the JSON string was inserted into the column and remove them from the column if possible. If it's hard to be removed, you can ignore such invalid values by using `TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP()` function.

Cast functions starting with `TRY_` silently return `NULL` if the argument cannot be parsed/cast and won't raise any error.

See Also:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#label-try-conversion-functions

Answer (score 4):

Using explicit format:

```
SELECT TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(col_name::VARCHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
FROM tab
```