# Snowflake convert from varchar to date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have `varchar` column `last_check` which looks like this

```
2021-10-28T20:40:56.00Z
```

How can I convert this to a timestamp?

I already tried

```
to date(2021-10-28T20:40:56.00Z )
```

or

```
select coalesce (TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(last_check,'YYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ')) as timestamp
from mde_history2
```

but with no success.

Any idea?

Comment: [Timestamp is not recognized Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69352361/5070879) - `TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(last_check, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')`

Answer (score 0):

as per Lukasz suggestion which can have the quotes removed:

```
select 
    '2021-10-28T20:40:56.00Z' as col_a
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(col_a,'YYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ') as og
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(col_a,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')as lukasz
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(col_a,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FF3Z')as no_quotes
;
```

gives:

[image]

because of the [Date and Time Formats in Conversion Functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion#date-and-time-formats-in-conversion-functions) tokens
your year was 3 Y's instead of 4, and your input has milliseconds, and your string was missing the `.FF`.

Lukasz's solution has the constant token double quotes as per the [doc's](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion#usage-notes):

> Anything in the format between double quotes or other than the above elements is parsed/formatted without being interpreted.

but given the `T` and `Z` are not explicit tokens they are ignored.
but if you have sometihng like an `YY` in the string, double quoting is required:

```
select 
    'YY2021-10-28T20:40:56.00Z' as col_a
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(col_a,'YYYYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') as hope
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(col_a,'"YY"YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"') as explicit
;
```

[image]